# $f:(0,+\infty)\to \mathbb R \, , f(x)=x+\frac{1}{1+x}$. Show $\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2} \ge f(\frac{a+b}{2}) \ge f(\sqrt{ab})$

Tags: calculus

$f:(0,+\infty)\to \mathbb R \, ,  f(x)=x+\frac{1}{1+x}$.

Show $\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2} \ge f(\frac{a+b}{2}) \ge f(\sqrt{ab})$ for any $ a,b \in \mathbb R^+$

I tried to actually plug in the values for $f$ in the inequality and it didn't get me anywhere, actually it is really ugly and nothing simplifies.

I don't know what to do. I know that $f(x)$ is increasing for any $ x \in (0,\infty)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you meant $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^+$ (they must lie in the definition domain of $f$). We have

$$f'(x) = \frac{x(x+2)}{(x+1)^2} >0 $$

so the right inequality follows from the increasing monotony of $f$ because

$$\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}$$

from AM-GM. Also

$$f''(x) =\frac{2}{(x+1)^3} > 0$$

so $f$ is convex. Therefore, the left inequality is just Jensen.

Comment: What is AM-GM, Jensen? I tried to prove $\frac{a+b}{2} \ge \sqrt{ab}$ but I did not know where to start.

Comment: @RaduGabriel, AM-GM is the Arithmetic Mean - Geometric Mean Inequality and for Jensen see here: https://brilliant.org/wiki/jensens-inequality/

Comment: $\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}$ is equivalent with $(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2 \geq 0$

Comment: This was really helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RaduGabriel In fact, the first inequality follows directly from the definition of convexity. We don't need to invoke Jensen's inequality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition

Comment: @bjorn93 I see it now, thanks!